# Editable table in HTML

Tags: html

Is it possible to **edit the data in table HTML** without using database and

**just double click the column I want to edit and it will allow me to edit it?**

Is this possible in HTML?

Comment: yes, with jquery. But you lost this changes when redisplay page.

Comment: well as BorHunter told on page refresh or reload the elements you added will be removed from your DOM ...... what exactly is the reason for you to try this ? Be more clear of what you want this for and we can get a solution for it.

Comment: i just want to edit the specific data in the table without going or using input textbox. I just want to double click it then edit and click enter to save. I want this to lessen the time consume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>How to become an editable HTML table with jQuery - MrBool Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("td").dblclick(function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        }
    });

$(this).children().first().blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
});
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="editableTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>Pedro Augusto</td>
            <td>pedro.augusto@myemail.com</td>
            <td>(21) 9999-8888</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>002</td>
            <td>Paula Silva</td>
            <td>paula.silva@mymail.com</td>
            <td>(81) 8787-8686</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>003</td>
            <td>Lucas Costa</td>
            <td>lucas.costa@myemail.com</td>
            <td>(84) 3232-3232</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how about in adding data in table? is this a same way?

Comment: when i click the add button there is a blank row that are enable to input some text and numbers

Comment: Hi, im back.. i have a problem again.. the running codes that you have shared to me was good but the problem is it did't update my csv file. it just change the table but not the data in CSV file. how to work with it?

Answer (score 1):

In pure HTML, up to a point using `contenteditable`. Its utility is limited though.

In HTML + JavaScript, yes. Utility is as much as you give it.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/anandnat/mLtjN/3/).

### HTML

```
<table class="editableTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>Pedro Augusto</td>
        <td>pedro.augusto@myemail.com</td>
        <td>(21) 9999-8888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>Paula Silva</td>
        <td>paula.silva@mymail.com</td>
        <td>(81) 8787-8686</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>003</td>
        <td>Lucas Costa</td>
        <td>lucas.costa@myemail.com</td>
        <td>(84) 3232-3232</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<button id="btn_newrow">Add New row</button>
```

### Javascript

```
$(function () {
$("#btn_newrow").click(function(){
    var test ="<tr><td>1</td><td>name</td><td>email</td><td>phone</td></tr>";
    $(".editableTable tbody").append(test);
});

$('.editableTable').on('dblclick', 'td', function () {

var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

$(this).addClass("cellEditing");
$(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
$(this).children().first().focus();

$(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var newContent = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    }
});

$(this).children().first().blur(function(){
  $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
  $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
});

});
});
```